# @gorhom bottom sheet as a separate component

Tags: react-native, bottom-sheet, react-native-modal

Is it possible to create a separate modal component that will be reused with different content on different screens?

I created a bottom sheet in a main index.js component and I can pass different content into the BottomSheet as an example below:

```js
<BottomSheet
  ref={bottomSheetRef}
  snapPoints={snapPoints}
  index={0}
  containerHeight={height}
  onChange={handleSheetChanges}
  handleComponent={() => {
    return <View style={styles.container}></View>;
  }}>
  <View style={styles.contentContainer}>{content}</View>
</BottomSheet>
```

However, I was not able to move the Bottom Sheet into a separate component: which was quite of a struggle, because the ref is coming undefined for me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to forward the ref to your custom component if it needs one. Check this one [Forwarding Refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 0):

this is my code. hope it can help you

```
// AppBottomSheetModal.tsx
export const AppBottomSheetModal = forwardRef((props: any, ref: any) => {
  const { t } = useTranslation();
  const snapPoints = useMemo(() => [1, 287], []);
  const handleSheetChanges = useCallback(() => {}, []);
  
  return (
    <BottomSheetModal
      ref={ref}
      index={1}
      snapPoints={snapPoints}
      // animationConfigs={animationConfigs}
      onChange={handleSheetChanges}
      handleIndicatorStyle={{
        backgroundColor: colors.grey500,
        width: 40,
        height: 5,
      }}
      backdropComponent={BottomSheetBackdrop}
      style={{ paddingHorizontal: 16 }}>
      <View style={styles.contentContainer}>{props.content}</View>
    </BottomSheetModal>
  );
});

AppScreen.tsx
const AddJobScreen = (props: any) => {
   const appSheetModalRef = useRef<BottomSheetModal>(null);
   ...
   return (
       <View>
           ...
           <Button
               style={styles.btn}
               title={'present bottom sheet'}
               onPress={() => {
                   appSheetModalRef.current?.present();
               }}
            />
           <JobsBottomSheet ref={appSheetModalRef} />
       </View>
   );
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).